# regular expression for string split in java

Tags: java, regex

I have string in the following form:

```
HOME(SPADE0) HOME(HEART0) HOME(CLUB0) BOTTOMCOL(CLUBA) ON(HEART2 CLUBA)
```

I would lilke to split it into

```
    HOME(SPADE0)
    HOME(HEART0)
    HOME(CLUB0)
    BOTTOMCOL(CLUBA)
    ON(HEART2 CLUBA)
```

splitting at space splits the last token also, which I don't want . What can be a suitable regular expression for it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

```
  String[] tokens = line.split("[)]\\s+");
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: yes i tried with some of the combinations, but could not succeed.

Comment: Please add the regular expressions you already tried and *how* you tried to ues them with Java.

Comment: @AdamGent do you expect anybody who is not expert in java should not work ever in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex (Using `Negative look-ahead`): -

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+(?![^(]*\\))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

It will only split on space, which is not in between `(` and `)`.

**OUTPUT**: -

```
[HOME(SPADE0), HOME(HEART0), HOME(CLUB0), BOTTOMCOL(CLUBA), ON(HEART2 CLUBA)]
```

**Explanation: -**

```
\\s+             // split on space (one or more)

   (?!           // Negative look ahead (Not followed by)
      [^(]*      // Anything except `(` (0 or more)
      \\)        // Ending with `)`
    )            // End
```

So, if your space is between, `(` and `)` as in `(HEllo World)`.

It will not match the above regex. Because the space in there is followed by : -

```
[^(]*  // Any string not containing `(` - World

\\)   // Ending with `)`
```

---

Note that, although this will solve your problem with `split`. But ideally, this should be done with `Pattern` and `Matcher`. As in @Marko's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Better split by matching the content instead of the delimiters:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\(.*?\\)").matcher(input);
final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) matches.add(m.group());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\(.+?\\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split on the ")" and then append it to all found tokens?

```
String [] results = str.split( ")" );

String token1 = results[0].trim() + ")"; // the trim is to remove leading spaces
```

This is assuming that all your data matches the presented format.