# Delimiter for grammar rules

Tags: java, grammar, delimiter

I try to figure out how I can extract the different Parameters of a given expression of my grammar. 
One grammar rule might look like this:

```
s( X, Y(X,-), T(Y(X,-),X,X) )
```

First I want to extract the leading string, in this case `s` and then I want to step through all the parameters, in this case `X`, `Y(X,-)`, `T(Y(X,-),X,X)`. It's also possible that I got no parameters at all and just `s` as a rule.

In the original grammar such an expression might have an arbitrary number of parameters, which might have parameters itself too.

At the moment I got the following code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(Rule);
String next = new String();


sc.useDelimiter("\\(");
next = sc.next();
//...Do something...//

sc.useDelimiter("");   
if(sc.hasNext()){   //Check if there are parameters
    sc.useDelimiter("\\)"); //Which delimiter should I use?
    while(sc.hasNext()){
       next = sc.next();
       //...Do something...//
    }
} else {
    return next;
}
```

I don't know which delimiter I should use to obtain the parameters, like `X`, `Y(X,-)`, `T(Y(X,-),X,X)` regarding the example.

Comment: Do you really want to scan your parameters using `scanner`? You can also use other ways. See this [recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298088/regular-expression-for-string-split-in-java/13298134#13298141)

Comment: I tried this regex: ,(?![^(]*\\)) 
and it works fine, as long as I don't get parameters without parameters. For example s(X,Y,Z) is a problem.

Comment: What problem did you get for that pattern? I think there is not a difference. It should also work for that.

Comment: If you apply that regex to `s(X, Y, Z)` then it won't work. You need to apply it on `X, Y, Z`. I assume that you already have retrieved the content inside the outermost parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah I already retrieved the "s(", and want all the parameters. But X, Y(-,-), Z, W for example, won't work with the regex above.
The problem is that I will first retrieve "X" and then "Y(-,-),Z,W".

Comment: The above regex will give you: - `"X", "Y(-,-)", "Z", "W"` for the above string. I thought this is what you wanted?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I forgot to get rid of the last paranthesis. I always worked on "X, Y(-,-), Z, W)". But there still remains a problem. As mentioned before I can also have nested parameters: "X, Y(-,A(-,B,-)), Z" won't work anymore.
I get "X" , "Y(-" , "A(-,B,-))" , "Z" but I want "X" , "Y(-,A(-,B,-))" , "Z".

Comment: Unfortunately, Regex is not good and suitable for parsing the nested parenthesis upto varying level. You would need to use some parser, or write of your own.

Comment: Too bad, then I'll write the parser myself. Thanks for your patience! :)